# Circular dependencies cannot exist in Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am a newbie in android. Got stuck cannot move forward without this. I don't understand where I am doing the mistake. Looked through the code for 2 hours but cannot find the error. I need serious help. Thank u in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:toomove ls="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.zodiac.sanghvi.jplreborn.Admin_ScoreCard">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Vs"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Team1 Vs Team2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BatsMen1"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
        android:text="Batting  :"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Vs"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Batting"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/BatsMen1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BatsMen2"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BatsMen1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Bowling  :"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BatsMen2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Bowling"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Batting"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Batting"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Bowler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Bowling"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Runs"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#f8f8f9"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Wickets"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#f8f8f9"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Runs"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Runs"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Runs"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Runs"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Overs"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Overs"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Overs"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Overs"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Overs"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Overs" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:text="Runs"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Runs"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Wickets"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Wickets"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:text="Wickets"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Wickets"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Wickets" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Choose"
        android:textColor="#f8f8f9"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Vs"
        android:text="Sultan Won The Toss And Choose to Bat"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Overs"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#f8f8f9"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Bowler"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

TextView with id `textView4` and TextView with id `Overs` are creating this circular dependency because:

TextView with id `textView4` is `alignLeft` and `alignRight` to the TextView with id `Overs`. Again, TextView with id `Overs` is `toRightOf` to the TextView with id `textView4`.

It's not possible because they can't be dependent on each other.

Comment: Yup Its Working  all thanks to u .And sorry as i cannot vote this as answer as my repo is not more than 15.Thanks again